# How to clear all variables in Scala REPL

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

Is there a quick command? I don't want to `Ctrl+d` and run Scala everytime I want to clear all variables. reset, clear and clean don't work and `:help` doesn't have anything listed

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use `:reset`

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0-RC2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_37).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val a = 1
a: Int = 1

scala> val b = 3
b: Int = 3

scala> :reset
Resetting interpreter state.
Forgetting this session history:

val a = 1
val b = 3

Forgetting all expression results and named terms: $intp, a, b

scala>
```

Comment: Thanks! I just realised I'm using scala 2.9.2, any idea what I can use there? `:reset` doesn't work